# Extend string class with static functions

Tags: c#, string, extension-methods

I'm trying to extend the 'String' class.
So far I got to create extended functions on declared string objects.

```
String s = new String();
s = s.Encrypt();
```

But I would like to create an extended function to the class itself.
In this case, something like : `String s = String.GetConfig("Test");`

What I tried so far:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Extensions.String
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
       // Error
        public string DecryptConfiguration
        {
            get
            {
                return "5";
            }
        }

        // Can't find this
        public static string GetConfig(string configKey);
        // Works, but not what I would like to accomplish
        public static string Encrypt(this string thisString);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Read about extension functions for example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add an extension method that you invoke like a static method on the class (e.g. `var s = String.ExtensionFoo("bar")`).

Extension methods require an instance of an object (like in your `StringExtensions.Encrypt` example). Fundamentally, extension methods are static methods; their trick is to use the `this` keyword to enable instance-like invocation (more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)).

Your best bet is some sort of wrapper:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Extensions.String
{
    public static class ConfigWrapper//or some other more appropriate name
    {
        public static string DecryptConfiguration
        {
            get
            {
                return "5";
            }
        }


        public static string GetConfig(string configKey);

        public static string Encrypt(string str);
    }
}
```

which could be called like this:

```
var str1 = ConfigWrapper.DecryptConfiguration;
var str2 = ConfigWrapper.GetConfig("foo");
var str3 = ConfigWrapper.Encrypt("bar");
```